# Python2.7 issue after updating Debian to Jessie

Tags: debian, python, apt

After running dist-upgrade on one system I am getting this error:

```
Sorry: TypeError: compile() expected string without null bytesdpkg: error processing package python2.7 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python:
 python depends on python2.7 (>= 2.7.9-1~); however:
  Package python2.7 is not configured yet.
```

Same error happens when doing a manual `dpkg -i`:

```
aleph /var/cache/apt/archives # dpkg -r python2.7
(Reading database ... 39002 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing python2.7 (2.7.9-2) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.0.2-5) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.58) ...

aleph /var/cache/apt/archives # dpkg -i python2.7_2.7.9-2_amd64.deb 
(Reading database ... 39380 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack python2.7_2.7.9-2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking python2.7 (2.7.9-2) over (2.7.9-2) ...
Setting up python2.7 (2.7.9-2) ...
Sorry: TypeError: compile() expected string without null bytesdpkg: error processing package python2.7 (--install):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.58) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.0.2-5) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python2.7
```

This also breaks all other packages (ie `rdiff-backup` or `xen`).

I'm a bit puzzled, as I can't find any clear reference online. I've rebooted the server, tried apt-get (auto)clean, etc. All seems good (not a corrupt package or fs?).

What are the next steps I can try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was caused by a corrupt file.

I installed `debsums`, and ran it on all files. Grepping on FAILED.

One of the corrupt files was `topics.py` (`/usr/lib/python2.7/pydoc_data/topics.py`).

I transferred the file from another, working machine, to that one, and reinstalled python2.7.

It worked fine after that.

I also had a couple of segfaults (other issue?) -- which went away after a reboot